# What is the source of crlt.pid= in a URL?

Tags: url, url-parameters

Looking at my page analytics in GA, I'm seeing that some URLs appear duplicated and have a parameter that I'm not familiar with at the end of the URL:

?crlt.pid=camp.amHWhFf5pRN1

The source and medium of the visits match what I would expect to be coming from our social media team.

Is there a tool they are using that is appending this parameter to the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

We just noticed this on our sites this morning and I segmented out visits that include pages with these URLs and the top referer, by far, is Pinterest. Also, one of our writers reports visiting a page via Pinterest and seeing this param appended, so it appears Pinterest appends this param to URLs on their end.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess we have no control over it.